Having trouble connecting to my database in Codename One
I have been fighting to copy my included SQLite database to FileSystemStorage, but I finally succeeded. I had to put the masters in my resources folder because I kept getting an "error opening connection" on the InputStream when I placed them in the src folder. Once I finally got them to copy, I am now getting the error trying to open the db with
Database db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("players.db");

I have added the backslash in front of the name, added the backslash database in front of the name, and added the FileSystemStorage(path) as the name, and I still get the connection error. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.
System M1 16" MacBook Pro, IntelliJ 2023.2.5, JRE 8
Edit:
My databases were created with DB Browser for SQLite
I have attached a simple build to test opening the database and inserting values. Both the db statement and the db execute throw "error opening connection" when building the app.
    private boolean savenadd() {
        String plnm = plyrname.getText();
        String pladd = plyradd.getText();
        String plph = plyrphn.getText();
        String plp1 = plyrpos1.getText();
        String plp2 = plyrpos2.getText();
        String plp3 = plyrpos3.getText();
        Dialog d = new Dialog("Database loading...");
            try {
                db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("players.db");
                String query = "insert into players (name, address, phone, pos1, pos2, pos3) values (plnm, pladd, plph, plp1, plp2, plp3)";
                db.execute(query);
            } catch (IOException err) {
                return (false);
            }
        return (false);
    }

Edit 2
The code for copying the databases to storage:
public class DBDemo extends BaseDesignForm {
    private Form currentForm;
    private Resources theme;

    public DBDemo() throws IOException {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
        Form dbimport = new Form();
        dbimport.show();

        Dialog.show("Databases", "Copying Databases", "OK", "Cancel");
        String pathp = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("players.db").toString();
        InputStream pi = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/" + "players.db");
        OutputStream po = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(pathp);
        Util.copy(pi, po);
        Util.cleanup(po);
        Util.cleanup(pi);

        String pathpl = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("plys.db").toString();
        OutputStream plo = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(pathpl);
        InputStream pli = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/" + "plys.db");
        Util.copy(pli, plo);
        Util.cleanup(plo);
        Util.cleanup(pli);

        String pathr = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("rndo.db").toString();
        OutputStream ro = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(pathr);
        InputStream ri = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/" + "rndo.db");
        Util.copy(ri, ro);
        Util.cleanup(ro);
        Util.cleanup(ri);

        String pathpm = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("pandr.db").toString();
        OutputStream pmo = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(pathpm);
        InputStream pmi = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/" + "pandr.db");
        Util.copy(pmi, pmo);
        Util.cleanup(pmo);
        Util.cleanup(pmi);
    }
}

Here is the error trace from the console, showing the error on EntrPlyr.java:78 in the savenadd() method, the line after the try is entered:
java.sql.SQLException: Error opening connection
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:179)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:105)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:113)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.openOrCreateDB(JavaSEPort.java:11778)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.openOrCreate(Display.java:4582)
    at com.touchlineassist.myapp.EntrPlyr.savenadd(EntrPlyr.java:78)
    at com.touchlineassist.myapp.EntrPlyr.lambda$new$0(EntrPlyr.java:59)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5341)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2424)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1300)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1218)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error loading native library: /org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64/libsqlitejdbc.jnilib
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:241)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:63)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java:50)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:175)
    ... 21 more

Edit 3
I right click-Analyze-Inspect Code on the pom file, and got this error

Edit 4
Installed fresh IntelliJ 2024.1.4, added the Codename One plugin. Created a new Initilizr for DBDemo, and copied in the SQL Sample/DBDemo.java code. When I run in the Simulator, the MyDB.db shell (no schema) is copied to the database folder, and then the Simulator fails with nullPointerException on the Util.copy(i, o) line in copyDB(). I took a screen shot after running the Simulator by right clicking on the pom file and performing Analyze-Inspect Code for the pom file.

Edit 5
Stack Trace
[EDT] 0:0:0,9 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:149)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:135)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:170)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:124)
    at com.example.dbdemo.DBDemo.copyDb(DBDemo.java:56)
    at com.example.dbdemo.DBDemo.lambda$start$2(DBDemo.java:79)
    at com.codename1.ui.Command$1.actionPerformed(Command.java:334)
    at com.codename1.ui.SideMenuBar$CommandWrapper.actionPerformed(SideMenuBar.java:1818)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:679)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5341)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2424)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1300)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1218)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Rendering frame took too long 250 milliseconds
CSS> null


Placing it in the resources directory will make it accessible to getResourceAsStream which is great if you want to ship your app with a database. But this is an unmodifiable file. You need to copy it to the actual location of the database which is what I explained to you in the other questions. This is something you need to do in CODE not physically copy the file. Since this is done dynamically when the app is run for the first time.

After moving my masters to the resources directory I was able to copy the databases to FileSystemStorage using the code you told me about, using Util.copy(i, o);, so I can use the databases in the shipping app. My problem now is opening the database so I can insert data in it to use.

I have tried all the examples I have found to open the database to work with either SQLmap or .insert, but I either get "error opening connection" or NullPointerException. I do want to thank you for all your help. Being an old-school database programmer has caused some relearning and experimenting.

sqlite isn't exactly a database in the same sense as JDBC... Can you include more of the code in the question? Specifically the copy and location target code. I'm guessing the problem is somewhere around there.

This code would throw an exception if the table wasn't created (it would also return false always). I asked for the code that copies the pre-existing file into place, I suggest you also look at the console when running it to see if errors are printed there.

Could this be an issue with DB Browser creating the master databases? What app have you used on macOS to successfully create databases that copied in? I thought of defining the database in Codename One, but I can't find support for that.

Just use this sample to see if it works there. If doesn't then the SQL file might be broken. In that case just extract the schema/data and build a simple Codename One application that runs the schema/SQL. Then copy the resulting file from there.

I used sqlite3 in Terminal to run the schema. One question, when I ran the copy for the first time, the code created a database folder in the .cn1 folder. Is that normal, and should the .db file be placed in the database folder, or on the top level of .cn1?

.cn1/database is the default database directory in a simulator. Where are you calling savenadd()? Ensure you are calling savenadd() after all databases are copied

I got a clean copy of the DBDemo to run. The DB copied to the Database folder from the src folder, but both choices in the side menu gave an "error opening connection" error. Is there a chance my libraries need to be cleaned? The creation has been successful 5 times, but no joy reopening the DB.

Do you mean copyDB? I'm guessing you didn't run it as the ant project? Did you place the db file in the right location under resources? Is there an error in the console ? Did you step over this with the debugger to see the copy was successful?

Progress: I placed the MyDB.db database in the src folder. I created a clean app with the DBDemo.java class and ran it in the Simulator. When I ran the class, copyDB found the file and copied it to the database folder within the .cn1 folder.  When I chose List Tables I got the same error caused by the openOrCreate(MyDB.db) call. I think I found the problem today. MyDB.db has 3 tables and the schema. All of the copies I have created in the database folder using copyDB do not have the tables or the schema.  So it seams my error is happening because I am not creating a valid db file with copyDB.

I finished my last test last night. I removed the database frame I created with Util.copy(i, o); from the database folder and changed the create sequence to using the db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("players.db"); , attempting to create the database/install the table using db.execute() code from the DAO tutorial. In the Simulator, the db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("players.db"); gave me the "[EDT] 0:0:0,5 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - java.io.IOException: Error opening connection" error. The only success my app has had is 5 unreadable database frame copys.

Today's attempts to create the database: I granted IntelliJ full disk access in Privacy and Security. I rebuilt the IDE and cleared everything. Still received the error from my previous comment.

Take the SQL demo. Change the database by creating a new table and adding data into it. Go to the ~/.cn1 folder and take the database file from there.  Replace the one in the project and delete the ~/.cn1 folder. Rerun the project and select the feature to copy the DB. Is your new table there? That process should work...

I'm sorry for the confusion. In my comment on 7.20 I should have said SQL Sample instead of DBDemo. DBDemo is the class name. As I noted in the 7.20 and 7.21 comments, when I ran the SQL Sample (DBDemo.java) in the Simulator. MyDB.db copied to the .cn1/database folder both times I ran the clean setup, but both times there was an "error making connection" error when I chose both List Tables and Tutorial in the side menu.

I opened MyDB.db copied to the database folder in DB Browser both times after the copy, and even though the tables are in the source MyDB,db, the myTable, t1 and temp tables are not copied, just the frame. To further test my disk access problem, I placed a copy of the source MyDB.db in the database folder, verified the tables were there, and ran the class in the simulator. Both List Tables and Tutorial still gave the "error making connection" error.

I will take a screenshot showing the pom file having 46 errors. I am thinking of changing the name of my IntelliJ work folder, re-installing IntelliJ, and running updates and adding the Codename One Libraries. I will create another clean install of SQL Sample, and see if my connection error persists. Thanks, @ShaiAlmog, for your help.

When I right click-Analyze-Inspect Code on the pom file it only showed 1 error today, but that involved the cn1libs module.

Added Edit 4 above.

That's the common pom not the parent pom. It won't find these things since they're defined in the parent pom.

Re-installed IntelliJ and created a new Initializr for SQL Sample. When I ran in the Simulator I got a nullPointerException on copyDB(i, o);. I built a new NetBeans Initializr for SQL Sample and ran it in the Simulator. This also gave a nullPointerException on copyDB(i, o);

Both runs created the MyDBdb shell in the .cn1/database folder

What's the stack trace for the null pointer exception?

Added the console trace above.

It's from this line which maps here. Your input stream is null which means it couldn't find the resource file. Make sure the resources directory is named correctly and that the file is in the root like you see in this project.

This trial has me wondering about my environment. copyDB finds the source database in the src folder and creates the database shell in the cn1/database folder, then fails. Since the shell has no size, the buffer size is zero, which causes the error. I wrote the copy class for my 4 databases, and all 4 shells were copied. When I then tried openOrCreate on my first database to save data to it, again because the shell was empty, the error opening connection shows as the access fails. Running SQL Sample had the same result. MyDB.db shell copied into cn1/database, failed when I tried List Tables.

I made sure IntelliJ had full disk access, and still created shells. I am concerned that my M1 system is not going to work. I am creating the playinfo screen in java, and will try to create jdbc access to verify. Thanks for your help.

I know that this code has been used thousands of times since Shai wrote it, so I know the code is not the problem. I cannot find the way to open the access to the path. Even though I gave IntelliJ read/write privileges, no change. As I side note, I also got the same errors running the code in NetBeans.

It's possible the code has an issue with the Arm JDK. Some of our dependencies were never migrated to ARM and it's possible that this is one of them.
